# React Google Cognito SSO

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito

Having real trouble implementing google SSO with my react app. I am trying to integrate it with Cognito and have followed this guide exactly - https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cognito-google-social-identity-provider

I believe I have set it up correctly, but the URL used to take users to the page where they sign in with google looks like this [image]

I want it to be the classic google sign in page where they can select their account. My URL is this https://kandir.auth.us-west-1.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=token&client_id=MYCLIENTID&redirect_uri=https://www.example.com/

Does anyone have any suggestions? Would really appreciate help

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like you the page you're trying to reach has enabled the social sign in, it should look similar to (but just Google) :
[image]

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-pools-hosted-ui-user-experience.html.

Are you using the correct clientId? Check the cognito console for your app client and it should have:

[image]